# After working for years, all of a sudden TNS listener not working today

Tags: oracle11g

Oracle 11g is being hosted on Windows 2008 server.  The Oracle listener service is running. This server has been working for years.  No idea what changed today.  Our database is down and I can't login.

If I run `lsnrctl stat` it shows this output

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=vpr-data)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

Also, I see in the clsc.log file the following error from today.

```
2016-10-11 10:37:45.448: [ default][3788]ut_read_reg:2:ocr registry key SOFTWARE\Oracle\olr cannot be opened. error 2
[    CLSE][3788]clse_get_crs_home: Error retrieving OLR configuration [0] [Error opening olr registry key. The system cannot find the file specified.
]
```

In the sqlnet.log I see this as well

```
VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 11-OCT-2016 09:46:10
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12541
    TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
    ns secondary err code: 12560
    nt main err code: 511
    TNS-00511: No listener
    nt secondary err code: 61
    nt OS err code: 0
```

Not a Oracle expert by any means. Can anyone help debug this?  I haven't been able to figure anything else yet playing around with the listener.ora or tnsnames.ora files either.

Answer (score 2):

We were able to finally figure it out.  The listener log file had gotten too large and the listener wouldn't start properly.  Thanks Oracle for great error messages that don't help at all lol

Comment: I agree. What a horrible database system.

Comment: how did you remove those log files?

Comment: I honestly don't remember. Possibly just copied the files to another network location and let the database start over with a new log.